# error on facedetection

Tags: android, eclipse, face-detection

I'am doing facedetection with the following java code as part of my project.iam getting a strange error

```
BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();

         /*BitMapFactory-Creates Bitmap objects from various sources, including 
          * files, streams, and byte-arrays. 
          */

         BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 

imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();

     imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();

    myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];

    myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight, numberOfFace);

     numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace); 

     }

//i get error over there in R.drawable.pics      
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pics, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
```

I am supposed to give the name of the pic file in pics but it keeps giving me an error
pics cannot be resolved or is not a field. So I set the name of the pic file as pic PS it's a jpg file in the drawable folder. I also named the file within single quotes as 'pic' ---it gives me Invalid character constant error.

I also named it within double quotes but it still doesn't work. I also named it 'pic.jpg' still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is another variable in your code named 'pics'.

Try saving it in a different folder, say MyPics. And name the picture differently, say xyz1.jpg

In this case write the line as:

```
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.MyPics.xyz1, BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
```

Also, did you initialise 'myBitmap' as a bitmap image? Meaning, did you include the line:

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
```

in your code, before performing the image read?

Comment: yes i did add Bitmap myBitmap; also i did as you said ie R.MyPics.xyz1; I also tried R.drawable.xyz1; doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Just check with following line of code:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inPreferredConfig =  Bitmap.Config RGB_565;
 Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon,options);
```

Let me know whether it works or not?
Also check image names which appears after you type *R.drawable.*

**EDIT:**

If still you are not able to access image from drawable, copy your image say pic.png to asset folder and access it using following code:

Updated Code:

```
try {
       InputStream bitmap=getAssets().open("icon.png");
       Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
       img.setImageBitmap(bit);
     } catch (IOException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: also after ive typed R.drawable it says in a small window create field 'drawable' in type'R'

Comment: AssetManager cannot be resolved to a type                 InputStream cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
    options.inPreferredConfig =  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 
    
        
   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); 
    
      InputStream istr = assetManager.open("pic.png"); 
      myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

Comment: i did Source → Organize Imports to important required packages       however iam now getting                                   InputStream istr = assetManager.open("pic.png")         Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: should i add a throws exception

Comment: Please clean and rebuild the project

Comment: img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); variable img cannot be resolved

Comment: should it be of type ImageView but then ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1); but then same problem will occur also id will have to be resolved

Comment: To clean project: In Eclipse, goto Project- Clean - select project to clean. Right click on ur project, build project.

Comment: gud... please share or select the answer. So that it will be helpful for other users